# updateOrInsert does not work well.when a record exist , it happens duplicate error

Tags: laravel

updateOrInsert does not work well.when a record exist , it happens duplicate error

Error says
(PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2021-08-03 00:00:00-96' for key 'records.records_date_company_id_unique'

```
        Record::updateOrInsert(
        ['company_id'    => (int)$request->id
        ,'date' => $request->delivery_date
        ,'amount'  => (int)$request->total_amount
        ,'created_at' => now()
        ]);
        return response()->json($request, '200', ['Content-Type' => 'application/json','Charset' => 'utf-8'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// I would like to add another response when it happens error
```

Migration define

```
class CreateRecordsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('records', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dateTime('date');
            $table->integer('company_id');
            $table->Integer('amount');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique(['date', 'company_id']);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `updateOrInsert` method accepts two arguments: an array of conditions by which to find the record, and an array of column and value pairs indicating the columns to be updated.

In your case, it should look something like below:

```php
Record::updateOrInsert(
    ['company_id' => (int) $request->id, 'date' => $request->delivery_date],
    ['amount'  => (int) $request->total_amount]
);
```